# Class for collection of objects

Tags: java, oop

If I have a class `Car` and would also like to maintain a list of `Car` objects, would creating a plural class `Cars` be better or would it be a good practice to make static methods in the `Car` class to contain a list of `Car`?

```
class Car {
    private String model;
    private String color;
    ...
    private static ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

    ...
    public Car {
        ...
        Car.cars.add(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Car is a single Object. You should create every car in a seperate class and add it there to a List. Not in the car class itself.

Comment: Personally i'd say it really depend of what you are trying to do with it. I'm not such a fan of adding a static list referencing his own class, but depending on your project it could do the trick. Can you explain the context and what you are trying to do?

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond It's actually a collection of user-entered data in an Android Application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, you would like your class to include the basic methods and attributes without knowing who is going to use it.
A class Car shouldn't be aware of the application logic; thus there is no need to know that you need a List of Cars. Moreover, imagine that you need to reuse this class for another application that requires either a Map of Cars or another Collection of Cars, why to carry this unwanted List?

In your case I would divide the application logic from the class logic and create the List in a separate Class that indeed requires it.